# How to read function-like macros?

Tags: c

I should implement these function-like macros, but I'm not sure I understand the syntax. Could somebody explain me how to read them?

```
#define msgsend(dest, payload) (SYSCALL(SYS_SEND,(unsigned int) (dest), (unsigned int) (payload),0))

#define msgrecv(source, reply) (((struct tcb_t *) SYSCALL(SYS_RECV, (unsigned int) (source),(unsigned int) (reply),0)))
```

Comment: There are no function macros. Macro with parameters just replaces the text. During the preprocessing the dest and payload in the msgsend will be put (as a text) into the right side of the macro

Comment: They are often referred to as "function-like macros", so that's what OP probably meant.

Comment: What do you mean by "implement" exactly? Those are implementations of macros.

Comment: it is wrong as people think that they can use maxcros as functions and some time ago someone asked why he cant recurse it.

Comment: @MikeDi: can you give some background on where you got these macros? `SYSCALL` should likely be another macro which does a system call, `SYS_SEND` would be an identifier specifying the type of the system call. But it's impossible to suggest what *you* should do with these macros.

Comment: if you want to see the macro expansion just preprocess the file (gcc option -E)

Comment: @Groo It's for a message passing service for a microkernel. SYSCALL is not defined yet.

Comment: @ikeDiM: yes, that's why I wrote you should give some background, since I am presuming you don't know how to do that, and nobody can suggest how to implement something for an unknown microkernel, running on an unknown platform.

Comment: @Groo yes I know but it's a lot of material. It's for an open source  ARM7TDMI emulator. You can find it here http://mellotanica.github.io/uARM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a macro `msgsend(dest, payload)` which will be expanded to

```
(SYSCALL(SYS_SEND,(unsigned int) (dest), (unsigned int) (payload),0))
```

Simplifying the above line

```
SYSCALL(SYS_SEND, (unsigned int) (dest), (unsigned int) (payload), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks,  so when I use msgsend(dest, payload) a SYSCALL with expanded parameters will be called.
Therefore I should implement the SYSCALL function, right?

Comment: Why down votes?  Did I do something wrong? Please leave a comment.

Comment: Well, for one thing, the simplification changes the meaning, given that `dest` and `payload` are placeholders.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz; Aaah! It just overlooked that when simplifying.

Comment: (unsigned)(-2/2) != (unsigned)-2/2

Comment: your simplification still goes too far. You do not know what the SYSCALL is

Comment: @PeterJ; I don't know much about this except this is an assembler instruction.